# System.Security.SecurityException: Security error while trying to consume WCF Data service in Silverlight 5 application

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, wcf-data-services, odata, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to consume a WCF data service in a Silverlight 5 application/.NET 4.0 application. I can see the data in the web browser as Atom feeds when i query the service manually.

However when i try to query the data via standard approaches i am getting the following error:

> {System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
>      at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Data.Services.Http.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)}

**Inner exception is null.** So no meaningfull information is available as yet.

### My Code

```
public partial class ProjectWindow : ChildWindow
{
XYZEntitis.XYZEntitis db = new XYZEntitis.XYZEntitis(new Uri("http://google.com/wcfdataservice1.svc/"));


    DataServiceCollection<XYZEntitis.Label> dscCats = new DataServiceCollection<XYZEntitis.Label>();
    CollectionViewSource customerAddressViewSource;
    ObservableCollection<XYZEntitis.Label> labelsBindingCollection = new ObservableCollection<XYZEntitis.Label>();
public ProjectWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnBack.IsEnabled = false;
        //Load Project categories
        BindProjectCategories();
    }
public void BindProjectCategories()
        {
            #region Code
            //#############################################
            //Approach # 01 : Raises Security Exception
            //#############################################
            //DataServiceQuery<XYZEntitis.Label> query = db.Labels;
            //query.BeginExecute(
            //    s =>
            //    {
            //        var state = s.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<XYZEntitis.Label>;
            //        var data = new ObservableCollection<XYZEntitis.Label>();
            //        foreach (var entity in state.EndExecute(s))
            //            data.Add(entity);
            //        cbCategoryName.ItemsSource = data;
            //    }, query);
            #endregion
            //#############################################
            //Approach No # 2 : 0 Records are returned
            //#############################################
            var cats = from cat in db.Labels select cat;
            //cats.ToList();
            dscCats.LoadCompleted += this.dscCats_LoadCompleted;
            dscCats.LoadAsync(cats);

            //#############################################
            //Approach # 3 : Security Exception
            //#############################################
            //var query = from cat in db.Labels select cat;
            //((DataServiceQuery<XYZEntitis.Label>)query).BeginExecute(OnCategoriesFecthComplete, query);
        }
private void OnCategoriesFecthComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var query = ar.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<XYZEntitis.Label>;

        // Get the response of the query.
        var response = query.EndExecute(ar);
        foreach (XYZEntitis.Label label in response)
        {
            labelsBindingCollection.Add(label);
        }
        cbCategoryName.ItemsSource = labelsBindingCollection;
    }
private void dscCats_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dscCats.Continuation != null)
        {
            dscCats.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
        }
        else
        {

            cbCategoryName.ItemsSource = dscCats;
            #region code

            //var data = (DataServiceCollection<XYZEntitis.Label>)sender;
            //cbCategoryName.ItemsSource = data;
            //cbCategoryName.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";   

            //customerAddressViewSource =
            //       (CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["customerAddressViewSource"];
            //customerAddressViewSource.Source = dscCats;
            #endregion
        }

    }
```

}

### Complete Stack Trace (Stack Trace 1):

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=An error occurred while processing this request.
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at ThreatModeler.Silverlight.ProjectWindow.OnCategoriesFecthComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.HandleCompleted()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass1a.b*_18(Object state2)
>          at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>          at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>     InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
>          Message=Security error.
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>               at System.Data.Services.Http.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>               at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          InnerException:

### Complete Stack Trace (Stack Trace #02)

> {System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing
>   this request. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error. 
>   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Http.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object
>   source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object
>   source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object
>   source, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   ThreatModeler.Silverlight.ProjectWindow.b_*0(IAsyncResult
>   s)    at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.HandleCompleted()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c*_DisplayClass1a.b__18(Object
>   state2)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me. In my service

1. Select Data under Installed Templates, and choose XML File.  Name the file clientaccesspolicy.xml.
2. Enter the following contents for the file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <access-policy>
>   <cross-domain-access>
>     <policy>
>       <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
>         <domain uri="http://*" />
>         <domain uri="https://*" />
>       </allow-from>
>       <grant-to>
>         <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
>       </grant-to>
>     </policy>
>   </cross-domain-access>
> </access-policy>
> ```